# Error while Installing dedupe conda package on windows

Tags: python, package, python-dedupe

[Error while installing dedupe package :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzcAv.png)

Please help me to solve this error:

After issuing `conda install -c derickl dedupe` I have received a `PackagesNotFoundError` on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I have never ever used anaconda but based on the error message I have visited and  [searched the package in question on anaconda.com](https://anaconda.org/search?q=dedupe) it catched my attention that the `derickl/dedupe` package is OSX only. Based on your screenshot you are using windows10 which is a completely different operating system. After filtering the packages the only win32/win64 compatible package is the [`fgregg/dedupe-hcluster`](https://anaconda.org/fgregg/dedupe-hcluster). After a [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=dedupe+windows+10+anaconda&oq=dedupe+windows+10+anaconda) I found [this old topic](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe/issues/407) titled with

> Package for conda

continuing with

> Dedupe is really pretty hard to install for windows users. It would be great to create a conda package.

The issue is closed by the user fgregg by [issue #407](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe/issues/453) claiming that he has created a wheel for windows install so this should be your answer:

`conda install -c fgregg dedupe-hcluster`